# Java - Force Inheritance of 1 of N Overridden Abstract Methods

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, abstract

Using Java 6, I have a situation where I want to force a child class to implement 1 of N overridden methods.  Let me explain with an example:

```
public abstract class TestClass {

  public abstract String isValidInput(ObjectOne objectOne);

  public abstract String isValidInput(ObjectOne objectOne, ObjectTwo objectTwo);

  public abstract String isValidInput(ObjectOne objectOne, ObjectTwo objectTwo, ObjectThree objectThree);

  //Lots of other Code

}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I do not know exactly how many objects or types of objects that I'm going to have to validate.  However, I do know that there is a limited number of possibilities.  (I used 3 in the example above but in reality it will likely be 5.)  What I want to do is force my child class to implement only **one** of the `isValidInput(...)` methods depending on the situation.

What is the cleanest way to solve this problem?

Thank you very much for you time!

Comment: Can you redefine the parent method(s)? For instance have it accept a [variable number of arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)?

Comment: `public abstract String isValidInput( InputObjectComposition allInput );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make it a composition of above answers with added generics ?

```
public interface Validator<T> {

    boolean validate(T... objects);
}

public class StringValidator implements Validator<String> {

    @Override
    public boolean validate(String... objects) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer so far.  As a follow-up on the solution above:  What if a particular implementation was known to only have 1 object (this will actually be very common).  So for example, what if I wanted one of the concrete class implementations above to have a signature of `public boolean validate(String string)`.  Is it possible to have an inherited signature like that with the solution above?

Comment: You can pass 1 argument to method validate(T... objects) and it will be just fine. Or you can have two interfaces: SingleValidator<T> with method validate(T object) and another one MultiValidator<T> with method validate(T... objects).

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and it works, although I feel that it is a little deceptive/confusing to the caller because in this case it will **always** be one parameter.  However, having two separate interfaces seems like a great solution in this case.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The only existing option in java is ellipsis (...) for a variable amount of arguments of the same type.

For example:

```
public void doSomething(Object... arguments){
    // something
}
```

arguments is in that case a simple array. Other options are probably rethinking the architecture. Which would be in my opinion the best option.

Comment: If the caller needs to be able to find out how many objects `doSomething` expects, add a method `int getValidationCount()`.

Comment: In a normal case I would pass some sort of container object which contains all properties as fields and add to this model class the meta information what needs to be validated. javax.validation would be an example for that.

Comment: I was unaware of the ellipsis feature of Java.  This is definitely pointing me in the correct direction!

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know exactly how many objects or types of objects

Then make all the objects you want to test, regardless of type, implement the same interface.  For example:

```
public interface Testable {
    public boolean isValid();
}
```

Then you can just pass a list of Testable objects:

```
public abstract class TestClass {
    public abstract String isValidInput(List<Testable> list);
}
```